# MySQL Unknown column error, but results seem ok, and query works in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is very strange. I am using MySQLi in PHP 5, and when executing the following query, i end up with an error in my httpd log similar as follows

```
[error] [client 192.168.0.1] Unknown column 'memberid' in 'where clause', referer: http://www.example.com/app/add-device
[error] [client 192.168.0.1] fetch_row[0] failed, referer: http://localhost/app/add-device
```

The query itself

```
        $this->db->query('
                            SELECT
                                `members`.`id`,
                                `members_timezones`.`timezone`,
                                `members`.`memberid`
                            FROM
                                `members`
                            RIGHT JOIN
                                `members_timezones` ON `members_timezones`.`memberid` = `members`.`id`
                            WHERE
                                `members`.`systemid` = ' . SYSTEM_ID . '
                                AND
                                `members`.`memberid` = ' . intval($this->user->uid)  . '
                                AND
                                `members`.`user` IS NULL
                            LIMIT 1
                        ');
```

Just to clarify, the above query does respond with expected results, however my httpd log is being spammed with an error that claims that column does not exist when it does.  It is also claiming that 'fetch' is not returning anything -- it does as well.

I would like to eliminate this false error from my system.

----- ADDED ------

The query results

```
id  timezone    memberid
12  America/New_York    2
```

The query results (EXPLAIN)

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  members_timezones   NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2    
1   SIMPLE  members NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   linked24.members_timezones.memberid 1   Using where
```

members

```
Column  Type    Comment
id  int(11) Auto Increment   
details text NULL    
user    varchar(35) NULL     
pass    varchar(512) NULL    
entered timestamp NULL [0000-00-00 00:00:00]     
updated timestamp NULL   
pass_key    varchar(32) NULL
systemid    int(11)  
memberid    int(11)
```

members_timezones

```
Column  Type    Comment
id  int(11) Auto Increment   
memberid    int(11)  
timezone    varchar(80) [UTC]
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the script or query that's causing those errors?

Comment: Is `SYSTEM_ID` always numeric?

Comment: Code looks ok so I would check the columnn names as the names are case sensitive.

Comment: Are you sure that this **exact** query worked in phpMyAdmin? Deducing from `members_timezones.memberid = members.id` it looks like you don't have `memberid` in `members` table. And that exactly what the error message is telling.

Comment: Yes, SYSTEM_ID is always a whole number.

Comment: @peterm :  Yes, this exact query worked.  Sample output :

Comment: @Dan Then please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20724130/edit) your question and provide exact table schemas and some sample data for both tables (a few rows will be more than enough) in textual form. Don't put code or sample data in comments. It's indecipherable.

Comment: @peterm I updated the question with the table structures, as well as sample query results, and the explain command run on the query.

Comment: @Don Great! Thanks. But what still missing is sample data for both tables and desired output for the query based in this sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by **aliasing** all the fields in use.

```
SELECT Table.Field As Field FROM Table
```

Not sure as to why this worked, but I am content that there is no further errors being reported.